# Why won't legal C code with 4 dashes compile in GCC?

Tags: c

This is legal C code.

```
INT m = -3;
INT t = ----m;
```

decrement(--) positive m (-m) and Negate (-)

(-)(--) -m

but fails to compile with  `error: lvalue required as decrement operand`
Does anyone know why this doesnt compile?

Comment: It's not legal C code. As the compiler is telling you (and it's even kind knough to tell you why)

Comment: What compile is that ?

Comment: "*This is legal C code*" No, it happens to be legal C++ code, but that's a different language, and it parses as `--(--m)` anyway..

Comment: this compiles `INT t = -m--;` so it stands to reason that the decrement operator can operate on m.

Comment: Where is `INT` defined? Did you meant `int`? (Since you're asking about subtle aspects of C syntax, it pays to be painfully precise.)

Comment: yes it means signed int, i write only freestanding non-hosted no libc apps, I only use and define very basic base types because i got tired of trying to keep track of all the size-t's, win_t's, uint8_t's, wchar, wchar_t's etc..

Comment: `int` is a keyword and the name of a built-in type. `INT` is non-standard. If you're going to use it in code you post here, please tell us how it's defined. Or just use `int`, which would have illustrated the issue just as well if not better.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compile `-- (-m)` nor `--(--m)` as in both cases the argument to `--` is not something that can be written to. There is no place to write back the value of `--` unless it's immediate argument is a variable or a dereferenced pointer. `-` doesn't work at all as that is now a temporary.

The output of a pre/post increment/decrement operator is again not something that can be written to (this is immediately clear on post, but it's also true on pre).

Note that C is not a backtracking language*; so it's not going to find the only legal parse of `-(-(-(-m)))` on its own. It did find it after I put spaces in `- - - - m` as expected.

<sup>*Having used one, you don't want it. The results are surprising.</sup>

Comment: `-- -- m` is a legal parse, but has a semantic error. (lvalue-ness is a semantic property, not part of the grammar). So even if it did backtrack along the lines you suggest, it still would never conclude `- - - - m`.

Comment: @M.M: I'm pretty sure you know what I mean. I have used a language defined to backtrack in a very similar way (semantics fed back into the grammar) until it yielded a program that was valid.

Answer (score 2):

`----m` is *not* `-`, `--`, `-`, `m`.

`----m` is `--`, `--`, `m` because the compiler always finds the *longest* token.

The compiler is telling you that `--`, `--`, `m` is an illegal construct.